# Why pass in a function parameter via an immediate function?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I understand that immediate functions' closures are used to create private variables; but I am not sure of the differences, if any, between the two below patterns:

```
var fn = function() {
    var p = param;
    ...
};
```

and

```
var fn = (function(p) {
   ...
})(param);
```

In both cases, `p`'s scope is limited to `fn`. So why do I sometimes see the second pattern?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, nor if you understand what you are doing?
In your first example, you create an anonymous function, and then store it to the variable `fn`, but in your second example, you create an anonymous function, run it, and store the output the the variable `fn`. So unless you're returning `p` in the second example, it should not be visible at all.
You are free to correct me, if I'm wrong ;)

Comment: You beat @Nasser by a nose, so I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 2):

The two code snippets you posted do not do the same thing.

In the first one, you are creating a variable `fn` which stores a reference to a function object. In the second code snippet, you are actually calling the anonymous function, and `fn` will store the return value.

**EDIT**

It seems you are unsure of the answers so I'll elaborate. Let's use an example to explain the use of each. I'm going to make up a simple function to demonstrate:

```
var param = 5;
var fn = function(p) {
    return p * 2;
};
```

When this is done, you will be able to use `fn` to call the function. So, you could later say:

```
var someVar = fn(param); // someVar will be equal to 10
```

On the other hand, your second example:

```
var param = 5;
var fn = (function(p) {
    return p * 2;
})(param);
```

`fn` will store the numeric value `10`

**NOTE**

In my answer, I changed your first function to include `p` as an argument.

Comment: Hm, you and "javascript is future" are correct in saying that `fn` is assigned a function object in the first example and the return value (if any) of the function in the second. But the reason I think the latter is used is because the calculations performed inside the function are only executed once. So for example, if `param` is a URL and the anonymous function returns an object with the query string properties and values, the function only executes once and assigns the return value to `fn`. In the first example, `fn` must parse the URL every time the function is called.

Comment: The second example is the one in which the function is executed only once. In the first example, a reference to the function object is stored and you can execute it as many times as you need.